# How to add a button to first item in ListView

Tags: windows, xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

Greeting,

I'm developing an apps for Windows Phone 8.1 and face some problem with ListView.

I wanted to place a button for the FIRST item in ListView, but it seem like I can't align center the button.

Below is the code I use currently:

```xml
<ListView>
    <Button Content="Jio!" Height="6" Width="362"/>
    <ListViewItem Content="ListViewItem"/>
</ListView>
```

Adding horizontalalignment='center' just wont work for the button.

The reason I want to do this is because I wanted the button to scroll together with the list, hence I'm placing it inside the ListView.

Please advice what can I do to achieve my purpose, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the ListView.Header content to place such a button instead of adding it as a child directly.

```
<ListView>
  <ListView.Header>
    <Button ... HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
  </ListView.Header>
</ListView>
```

By default, the ListViewItems are left-aligned. You will eventually have to replace their Template in order to center-align it (HeaderTemplate Property).